# Как показать мой ip-адрес в textbox1

Tags: c#, winforms, ip-address

Как показать мой ip-адрес в textbox1 C# Windows Forms

Можно вывести в textbox1 мой ip адрес?

Comment: Легко: получите адрес и присвойте его свойству Text элемента TextBox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach (System.Net.IPAddress ip in System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList) 
{
     textBox1.Text = ip.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Linq;

namespace MainApp
{
    public partial class HostsControl : Form
    {
        public HostsControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            textBox1.TextChanged += TextBox1_TextChanged;
            textBox1.Leave += TextBox1_Leave;
        }

        private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;

            // We remove all characters except numbers and dots
            string cleanedText = Regex.Replace(textBox.Text, @"[^0-9.]", "");

            // Removing unnecessary dots from the text
            cleanedText = Regex.Replace(cleanedText, @"\.{2,}", ".");

            // We delete the point at the beginning, if there is one
            if (cleanedText.StartsWith("."))
            {
                cleanedText = cleanedText.Substring(1);
            }

            // Delete the dot at the end if there is one and there is no digit after it
            if (cleanedText.EndsWith(".") && (cleanedText.Length == 1 ||
                !char.IsDigit(cleanedText[cleanedText.Length - 2])))
            {
                cleanedText = cleanedText.Remove(cleanedText.Length - 1);
            }

            // We remove the extra points if there are more than three of them
            int dotCount = cleanedText.Count(c => c == '.');
            while (dotCount > 3)
            {
                cleanedText = cleanedText.Remove(cleanedText.LastIndexOf('.'));
                dotCount--;
            }

            // We remove the extra digits in octets and check the range of values
            string[] octets = cleanedText.Split('.');
            for (int i = 0; i < octets.Length; i++)
            {
                if (octets[i].Length > 3)
                {
                    octets[i] = octets[i].Substring(0, 3);
                }

                if (int.TryParse(octets[i], out int num) && num > 255)
                {
                    octets[i] = "255";
                }
            }
            cleanedText = string.Join(".", octets);

            textBox.Text = cleanedText;
            textBox.SelectionStart = textBox.Text.Length; // Move the cursor to the end of the text
        }

        private void TextBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;

            // We check the format of the IP address after entering all octets and dots
            if (!Regex.IsMatch(textBox.Text, @"^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$") ||
                !IPAddress.TryParse(textBox.Text, out _))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect IP address format.", "Error:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                textBox.Text = ""; // Reset the contents TextBox
            }
        }

        private void HostsControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Actions when loading the form
        }
    }
}
```

I used a different approach, a complete ban on entering anything other than numbers or dots, and I got a smart field.

Comment: на ruSO _нужно_ писать на русском как вопросы, так и ответы (включая комментарии в коде).